Django: Как исправить скрипт шаблона, чтобы выводились разные картинки в цикле?
Получаю из БД путь к картинке, путь корректный. Но в цикле почему-то путь не читается из переменной :( Кто может, помогите!
views.py:
def index(request):
    
    themes = QuizCategory.published.all()
    
    context = {'themes': sorted([(x.id, x.title, x.image) for x in themes])}
    # проверка доступа к данным
    print(themes[0].image)
    return render(request, 'first_quizz/index.html', context)

index.html:
   {% for theme in themes %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2 text-center border border-2 rounded-3 ">
                {{ theme.0 }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 text-center border border-2 rounded-3 ">
                {{ theme.1 }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 align-items-center border border-2 rounded-3 ">
                <img src="{% static '{{theme.2}}' %}" alt={{theme.2}}>
            </div>
        </div>
   {% endfor %}

Отображение:

При смене в цикле переменной на конкретный адрес, все работает:
index.html:
<div class="col-2 align-items-center border border-2 rounded-3 ">
     <img src="{% static 'images/cat_imgs/django.jpg' %}" alt={{theme.2}}>
</div>

Отображение:


Так вы ж указали не переменную theme.2, а строку '{{theme.2}}', вот эта строка и вставляется как есть

Я это понимаю, но как правильно сделать, не знаю. Убираю кавычки - вылетает ошибка: Could not parse the remainder: '{{theme.2}}' from '{{theme.2}}'

Очевидно не {{theme.2}} а theme.2

@andreymal
Спасибо огромное! Даже не пришло в голову, что переменную можно было использовать без {{}}.

Решение подсказал @andreymal в комментариях к вопросу.
Все заработало :)


так вы напишите само решение.

Нужно заменить {{theme.2}} на theme.2
